# Suggestion: It needs to be clearer which sites are available?

Tags: feature-request

Excuse my newb-on-meta big boots.

I find it frustrating that I often don't know where to post my question being a jack of all trades. I suggest it is made clearer which StackExchange sites are available and this facility is made obvious on any one of the sites.

If it's there I've missed it numerous times (hence it is broken) and I have always start by  browsing "All sites" for a similar question. Frankly I'm finding this multiple-personality thing so very unusable and braindead and nothing like as useful to me as the original SO.

Still... I'm sure we all want the site to succeed.

Answer (score 7):

If you're looking for a complete list of sites with a short description, you can use the nifty StackExchange button in the left corner (where notifications appear) and check out the tab labeled, "all sites."

[image]

Comment: @studiohack I would have been much faster but I spent a good 10 minutes browsing MSO for the name of that button.... I never found it and settled for "nifty StackExchange button" lol.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66712/poll-in-background-for-stackexchange-multicollider-superdropdown-inbox-events-a - see the title of this question for the name of it...add question to your MSO favorites...

Comment: @studiohack That is the exact question I was looking for!! I knew I saw it before... thank you!

Comment: That list is spectacularly unhelpful because a)it's a randomly sorted list in a tiny window, b) nothing in the UI guides me there, c) all I can do is scroll up and down, not search or get suggestions.

Answer (score 7):

Visit the [**Stack Exchange Site Directory**](http://stackexchange.com/sites?sort=default) for a complete list of sites and a brief description of each. The Site directory is categorized now as well to help you narrow down your site choice.

[image]

Comment: OP: @Kyle was first in posting, if you accept an answer about the Site Directory, please accept his. Thanks!

Comment: Now **that** is more helpful but as a normal (CompSci grad of 20+ years) user looking for help **nothing** in the UI guides me there. Familiarity with the site will prevent established users like you and @studiohack from seeing this kind of thing. I'm going to give an answer which shows a use case that I don't think you are addressing. But thanks - I'm seriously not trying to wind you folks up.

Comment: appreciate the different point of view @Dizzley

Comment: "respect" @studiohack

Comment: what do you mean @Dizzley?  I'm confused by you putting respect in quotes?

Comment: Sorry - failure to communicate on my part. I was simply trying to offer you some respect for your gracious comment. No curve/slant was implied or intended.

Comment: oh, thanks @Dizzley, no problem :)

Answer (score 4):

[You can also come into our Chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118)s, I'm quite sure the users there will help you pick the right site.

Sadly, there's no guide to Stack Exchange or a global FAQ. Your best bet is to read the FAQs on any site you like or have a look at the question that are being asked, whether it's on-topic or not.

However, I wonder how often this really happens, because surely you don't have questions for all our (currently) 46 sites? So worst case, you'd only have to figure out what your top five sites are about.

Also, when a question doesn't seem to fit one site or the other, you probably have to rethink your question, because you obviously haven't localized the problem well enough. This doesn't mean we can't help you, but that's why I can highly recommend asking for some peer review in Chat, to help you figure out what the real problem is!

Comment: I agree, there is usually always an experienced user in the SU Chat rooms who can point you in the right direction... +1

Comment: Chat rooms? Seriously? I really don't want to engage that deeply with SE - I want self-service. That's like asking someone online "How do I use Google to search. A great site/service "just works".

Comment: I haven't "localized the problem" enough? Scenario: I have a web form that won't email me a report. I start digging into jQuery, then it's the database, then it's mailx, then it's an Ubuntu issue. I am forced to think "where do I post my questions?" One time it's StackOverflow, next it's SuperUser, next it's SomewhereElse. I lose track of all the factors that matter to my evolving problem.**This is the tail wagging the dog**. Just help me, people. I think the StackExchange sites form clusters particularly the IT/tech ones and the people I need to help **right now** are in there somewhere.

Comment: Ivo - "Sadly, there's no guide to Stack Exchange or a global FAQ. Your best bet is to read the FAQs on any site you like or have a look at the question that are being asked, whether it's on-topic or not." - Exactly.

Comment: Choosing a site is hard. See the taglines: "Stack Overflow - Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers" versus "
Super User - Q&A for computer enthusiasts and power users" versus "
Programmers - Q&A for expert programmers interested in professional discussions on software development". **Permutate any of professional/enthusiast/programmer/software/development**

Comment: I disagree about the problem localization, if you just ask: why won't this site mail me a report? Then you're asking a far too general question and are likely to get poor answers. As soon as you've found what the potential cause is: your OS, your browser, your code, the server. Then you know where to ask the question.

Comment: Don't take it the wrong way, I agree that our user experience suffers on several points, but given how well it worked for a lot of users, I don't think its **that** big a problem either. As for chat, how is that worse than asking it on Meta? You want our help don't you?

Answer (score 2):

From a newbie POV, I agree that it is very difficult to decide between the sites. After much searching I did find there's a more detailed description available once inside a site, from the About button (at the top next to the search bar).

I would have expected this information to be available as a drop down description within the sites directory. It would have definitely saved me a lot of time.